# How do I uniquely identify a Java Mail Message using IMAP?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

IMAP Message in Java Mail is identified by it's relative position number which starts from 1.

refer,
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/Message.html#getMessageNumber()

Message number is a temporary details.

Is there a way to permanently uniquely identify a mail/message which accessing a mailbox via IMAP using Java Mail API which holds true across sessions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the UIDFolder interface, which exposes the IMAP UID capability.

Comment: How to "get" the concrete implementation of that UIDInterface ? Code Sample would make  your answer complete and acceptable :)

Comment: UIDFolder uf = (UIDFolder)folder;

Comment: All the Folder objects that the IMAP provider returns implement the UIDFolder interface.

Comment: does another message get the same UID if i delete the old messages?

Comment: No.  Read the IMAP RFC for details.  You also need to consider the UIDVALIDITY.

Comment: Can the UID also be obtained from the Message headers? Just looking for a more OO way rather than relying on the folder to get the message property.

Comment: The UID is not in the message headers.  The UID is metadata managed by the IMAP server.

Comment: Is there a way to read a specific message with a given UID using JavaMail API?

Comment: Did you look at the [UIDFolder interface](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html#getMessageByUID-long-)?

Answer (score 11):

You can get a unique identifier for a message using the following code as an example

```
Folder folder = imapStore.getFolder("INBOX"); // get reference for inbox folder
UIDFolder uf = (UIDFolder)folder; // cast folder to UIDFolder interface
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY); // open folder
Message messages[] = folder.getMessages(); // get all messages
Long messageId = uf.getUID(messages[0]); // get message Id of first message in the inbox
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this because I think this will help

If you want to loop over the messages and get uids the above code does not do got performance as you have to loop and get uid, easy way to get that with the messages is below

```
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
UIDFolder uf = (UIDFolder)emailFolder;
Message messages[] = emailFolder.getMessages();
            
FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
//profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS);
//profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
profile.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
emailFolder.fetch(messages, profile);
```

this will get the messages with the uid

after this if you loop and do uf.getUID(messages[i]); you will get the uid but this time it will be faster.