# Is there any solution to download email attachment by passing particular email Message ID in Java Using POP?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

Currently working on wso2 esb with JavaMail API. what i want to do here is that  **download unreaded email(Gmail) attachment to some local folder**. 
   In ESB end, reading unreaded email and fetching unreaded email's message id task is over and also passing that message id  from esb to java also done.From java end, need to **download email attachment to that particular message id** which is coming from esb end.
  I don't know how to download email attachment for that particular message id in java.

Could you please help me out to find solution?
 Thanks in Advance,

Following code, download all email attachment to some local folder.need to **download attachment only for that particular message id**

```
public void downloadEmailAttachments(String host, String port,
            String userName, String password) {

     Properties properties = new Properties();


        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", port);


        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",
                String.valueOf(port));
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        try {
        Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect(userName, password);  
        Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();


        for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
            Message message = arrayMessages[i];
            Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
            String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
            String subject = message.getSubject();
            String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();

            String contentType = message.getContentType();


            String messageContent = "";

            // store attachment file name, separated by comma
            String attachFiles = "";

            if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {

                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                    MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                    if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                        // this part is attachment
                        String fileName = part.getFileName();
                        attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                        part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                    } else {
                        // this part may be the message content
                        messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                    }
                }

                if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                    attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                }
            } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                    || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                Object content = message.getContent();
                if (content != null) {
                    messageContent = content.toString();
                }
            }

            // print out details of each message
            System.out.println("Message #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            System.out.println("\t From: " + from);
            System.out.println("\t Subject: " + subject);
            System.out.println("\t Sent Date: " + sentDate);
            System.out.println("\t Message: " + messageContent);
            System.out.println("\t Attachments: " + attachFiles);
        }

        // disconnect
        folderInbox.close(false);
        store.close();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        System.out.println("No provider for pop3.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not connect to the message store");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no efficient way to do this using POP3.  POP3 will require the client to read at least all of the headers of each message in order to find the message that matches the messageId.  IMAP can do this much more efficiently.

Using either protocol, you can use the [Folder.search](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) method with a [MessageIDTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/MessageIDTerm.html) to find the right message.

Note also that you'll want to fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) in your code.

Comment: Hi @Bill Shannon,
In ESB end, retrieved emailmessageID as "16cc0b2b30c16f11". but passing this same as String messageId using MessageIdTerm which doesn't work. Can you give me solution in order to fetch email messageId in java, if it is possible, i'll compare both esb and java messageId ,and proceed further in my project.Awaiting for your response.

Comment: Try using "<16cc0b2b30c16f11>".  If that doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Comment: Hi @BillShannon
I open github account just now and created issue on Github, but don't know exact assignee name to assign that issue.Can you provide some details regarding that? and also didn't see my raised issue in https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug page

Comment: It's an issue in your program, or perhaps in the ESB product you're using.  If you use the ID in the header, I'm sure JavaMail will find the message.  Post the debug output if you think that's not working.  I have no idea how to get your ESB product to give you the ID you need.

Comment: Hi @BillShannon,
I thought that there is no issue in ESB MessageID, why because is after reading unread mail it will give some payload like **{
   "Body": {
      "jsonObject": {
         "messages": {
            "id": "16d420e11232864e",
            "threadId": "16d420e11232864e"
         },
         "resultSizeEstimate": "1"
      }
   }
}** , this format is same as mentioned in below url from gmail API. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages

Comment: If that's the hex representation of a Gmail message ID, you'll need to use the JavaMail ["gimap" protocol provider](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/package-summary.html) and the [GmailMsgIdTerm search term](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/gimap/GmailMsgIdTerm.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have message id, it is very simple. You have the getMessage() function on the Folder object which you can use for a single message

```
Message message = folderInbox.getMessage(messageId);
```

This should work.

*** I suggest you to go through the JAVA docs for the API

Comment: Hi @Hari,
Thanks for your information. i am getting email message ID as 168e5f6538584e7e. how can i set this value to variable called messageId(int type)?
Tried:getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "168e5f6538584e7e"
 **String msgId="168e5f6538584e7e";
 int msgnum=Integer.parseInt(msgId); 
Message message = folderInbox.getMessage(msgnum);**

Comment: I am not sure what  is the id the method is taking. In your original program, could you please check what is the values for id for each message and see what you are getting and what's there i the message are same or different? Also looks like the message you are getting is a Hex number and could be a very big number.

Comment: My Apologies. the getMessage() documentation says, the message id is always a relative position of the message in the folder. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: The following StackoverFlow question may offer help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435947/how-do-i-uniquely-identify-a-java-mail-message-using-imap

Comment: Hi @hari,
Thanks for your effort,